# What languages are required for an mmo browser based game?

Tags: java, networking

I asked this on gamedev.stackexchange.com, got nothing. Please fix tags if I did any incorrectly

What 'Things' are required for this sort of game? I understand java, c++, javascript, and objective c (iphone programming) fairly well, however I know nothing about networking programming, but I do know about networking in general (packets, mac addresses all that good stuff)

So this is my main question: for a game like Tribal wars, Evony, Shadowland online, travian, what programming languages do I need to know to take this on and finish it by myself? I'd imagine that most of it will be done in java, but for the whole connecting other players, combat, leader boards and (most importantly) making online payments for things, what languages should I learn for developing something like this? So what programming languages do I need to look in to.

Also, I am posting the game on a game-making website so I will not need to design a webpage or anything, I would just sell the straight-up game to them.

Comment: `... finish it by myself` - good luck, that quite huge of a task for a sole programmer.

Comment: I would say to learn a server side and client side language (maybe PHP and Javascript) to run the game.  Also you will need to know how to do database queries (SQL).  You will need to know some HTML (not really a language).  You can look into PayPal API to accept payments (it's pretty easy to get started).

Comment: @Thomas I'm aware of that ^_^ unfortunately I do not know any other programmins irl that know enough to actually help me.

Comment: @Boundless I'm not hosting a website so html is not required, I'd post it on an existing website. Also, are you saying I make the game in javascript instead of java?

Comment: I think that if you are motivated and talented enough that won't be a problem.  Yes, it will take time, but it will be very rewarding.

Comment: @Boundless its more of a self improvement project. This time of game requires things that I need to know, plus if I finish it I might make some money.

Comment: @Gabe yes, if it is to be ran on the web and you want people to play it I would use Javascript on the client side.  I would look into HTML5 also.  You don't validate data on the client side, you do that at the server (you don't want them to change how much gold they have for example).  There are many server side languages you could use.  If it will be housed on a windows server you could use c# instead of PHP (PHP was just one suggestion, since I'm familiar with it).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5504/discussion-between-boundless-and-gabe)

Comment: @Boundless post everything you've posted in comments into an answer because it is an answer :) It was very useful information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Networking programming isn't a different language. You will need to learn networking library/API in the language of your choice. However it's more difficult then single session application. Not sure which language is "easier" for networking, but I'm sure java, c++ will support networking library for the backend.

and MMO browser base application is no easy task. When you start learning, try to first make a multiplayer battleship game/tic tack toe/ etc. Start SMALL. Once you make that, build of your skill sets. a MMO could take up to a year to develop. But don't let that shy you away from learning!

I did a quick search on 'java networking two players 
http://www.cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/

and this tutorial might be a good start for making that two player tic tack toe. Start small, learn, success!

Comment: `a MMO could take up to a year to develop` that's a _very_ optimistic estimate :)

Comment: I should mention here that Java browser based games are a very arduous undertaking. Here's one of my favorite pictures (although you shouldn't ever use Rails to do MMOs) http://www.amedias.org/img/java_vs_rails_books.jpg

Comment: @varatis: I agree, there are really more books available for Java than Ruby... ;-)

Comment: @Traroth I see what you did there XD

Comment: Its not a "Runescape" MMO that I had in mind, just one of those image based click and level up games.

Comment: I've made a few game before, and taking a simple idea all the way through the development process to completion is pretty difficult.

Answer (score 2):

I would say to learn a server side and client side language (maybe PHP and Javascript) to run the game. Also you will need to know how to do database queries (SQL). You will need to know some HTML (not really a language). You can look into PayPal API to accept payments (it's pretty easy to get started).

If it is to be ran on the web and you want people to play it I would use Javascript on the client side. I would look into HTML5 also. You don't validate data on the client side, you do that at the server (you don't want them to change how much gold they have for example). There are many server side languages you could use. If it will be housed on a windows server you could use c# instead of PHP (PHP was just one suggestion, since I'm familiar with it).

Good luck with your adventure, it will be a great learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I'd say you should be fine with Java, HTML, Javascript, SQL, XML and some libraries based on those languages.

IMHO your client would mostly consist of HTML and Javascript (you might use flash but it will be dropped in favor of HTML 5) using AJAX to communicate with the server.

The server itself might be written in Java and would run the game for each player. The communication between the client and the server would then consist of player commands, screen updates etc. but no game logic would actually run in the client.

If performance might become an issue and you have hardware constraints, you might consider writing the server in C++. However, I doubt that would be worth the hassle, since most often performance bottlenecks are caused by bandwidth, algorithmic implementations etc. Thus, I'd recommend implementing the server in Java, possibly using application server technologies to get you started faster.

*Edit*

As requested by Gabe here's a short summary of what each "language" would do in this context:

- Java: most of the logic
- Javascript: mostly for client side animations and communication
- HTML: client side ui
- SQL: you'd store game state, players etc. in a database so you'd need SQL to query the database.
- XML: in most cases use for AJA**X** as well as configuration

That's just a rough list though.

Comment: Hey could you edit into your answer: individually, what would javascript do, what would sql and xml do (for the game)? Like what purposes do each one serve

Comment: Good list, I'd concur. If you're not particularly fond of doing massively concurrent network service programming, however, I'd strongly recommend you use an existing, perhaps open-source, server core. There are several available in Java, that can be extended with your particular game logic, many of which have JSON or XML interfaces that could be adapted for a JavaScript/HTML-5 client.

Since I'm personally rewriting a Java-based MMO server into Lisp, though, I would personally advocate either of them for the server logic :-) and also as a matter of taste, I prefer JSON over XML for the data.